# Prevent Cross Site Scripting but still support HTML file upload

Tags: security, file-upload, xss

I have a web application where user can upload and view files. The user has a link next to the file (s)he has uploaded. Clicking on the link will open the file in the browser (if possible) or show the download dialog (of the browser). Meaning that, if the user upload an html/pdf/txt file it will be rendered in the browser but if it is a word document, it will be downloaded.

It is identified that rendering the HTML file in the browser could be a vulnerability - Cross Site Scripting.

What is the right solution to this problem? The two options I am currently looking at are:

1. to put Content-Disposition header in the response to make HTML files downloaded instead viewed in the browser.
2. to find some html scrubbing/sanitizing library to remove any javascript from the file before I serve it.

Looking at the gmail, they do the second approach (of scrubbing) with having a separate domain for the file download - may be to minimize/distract the attack surface. However in this approach the receiver gets a different file than what was sent. Which is not 'right' in my opinion; may be I am biased. In my case, the first one is easy to fix. But I wonder if that is enough, or is there any thing that I overlook!

What are your thoughts on these approaches? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I can see 3 posible attack types (maybe there are more):

1. Client side code execution

As you said, your web server may serve a file as HTML and run javascript code on the client. This can be avoided with `Content-Disposition` but I would go with MIME types control through `Content-Type`. I would define my known type of files (e.g. pdf, jpeg etc.) and serve them with their respective [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) (e.g. `application/pdf`, `image/jpeg` etc.). Anything else I would serve it as `application/octet-stream`.

2. Server side code execution

Althougth I see this as an out of topic attack (since it involves other parts of your application and your server) be sure to avoid executing files on the server (e.g. PHP code through LFI). Your webserver should not access directly the files (e.g. again PHP), better store them somethere not accesible through a URL and retrive them on request.

Think if here you are able to reject files (e.g. reject .exe uploads) and ask the user to zip them first.

3. Trust issues

Since the files are under the same domain, the files will be accesible from javascript (ajax or load as script) and other programs (or people) may trust your links. This is also related to the previous point, if you don't need unzipped exe files, don't allow them. Using an other domain may mitigate some trust problems.

Other ideas:

- Zip all files uploaded
- Scan each file with antivirus software

PS: For me sanitization would not work in your case. The risk of missing something is too high.

Comment: Why would you prefer Content-Type over Content-Disposition? The other potential vulnerabilities you have mentioned are eliminated; thanks for pointing out them.

Comment: Because it can be used in the same way but with more benefits. Seting `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream` is esentially the same with `Content-Disposition`, but at the same time you will be able to allow the file types you consider safe for the client. Additionally, you may want to discard the names of the files since they are also an untrusted piece of data, you may keep only the extension (if any).

Comment: Wont it be hard for the browser to chose the appropriate application in the download dialog for the file. May be it will use the file extension, but extension of the file is not mandatory hence content-type should be the source of truth.

Comment: I don't think that the browser is going to chose an application. This depends on which app is registered to open the specified file extension, but it depends on the OS. What the browser may do is save the file with an extension associated with the MIME type, if it is able to recognize it. All these are also associated with the user experience you want to offer. If you don't care about lettings the browser open the file, just send them all for download.